# How to make eclipse be based on degrees?

Tags: eclipse, trigonometry, degrees, radians

As much as I am confortable with using degrees I am unconfortable with using radians, which is much. This makes it a real pain for me to use radians for the trigo functions in eclipse. Is it possible to use the trigo functions with degrees instead of the default radians?

Comment: Write your own functions then.  if you also need help formatting angles, look at ICU4J and its extended `RuleBasedNumberFormat`.  It isn't trivial, but you can format longitudes as 17°23′39″ W, for example.

Comment: If you're comfortable with degrees, then there's no reason you shouldn't also be comfortable with radians -- it may seem daunting, but radians are by far and away the proper way to handle angles, and all you really need to know is that `s = rθ`, where `s` is the arc length, `r` is the radius, and `θ` is measured in radians. (From this, it can be inferred that there are `2π` radians in a circle.) Either way, you'll have to become familiar with switching back and forth, because while the trig functions use radians, other Java methods use degrees (i.e. Arc2D).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a built-in function called Math.toDegrees(double) that you could call on your number to convert it into degrees. Does that work for you?

There's also a Math.toRadians(double) function as well.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Answer (score 2):

java.lang.Math; method

```
static double toDegrees(double angrad)
```

Converts an angle measured in radians to an approximately equivalent angle measured in degrees.

Reverse is also there

```
static double toRadians(double angdeg)
```

Converts an angle measured in degrees to an approximately equivalent angle measured in radians.